# qq.FileUploader doesn't work when loaded in AJAX popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, file-upload

So I got a dialog box that is loaded dynamically using AJAX, in that box, I have a file input that is replaced with Valums qq.FileUploader. I do call the init on the FileUploader after loading the content, my input box gets replaced properly by the FileUploader.

As you can see in the picture below, the input gets replaced by everything, and the new "hidden" input, is there. Problem is that I can't click on it. However, I can drag-and-drop files correctly. So, the upload still works, but only drag-and-drop. This has been tested with Chrome and Firefox, both on Windows.

[image: Image of dialog with input replaced]

See [Valums qq.FileUploader doesn't work when it's initialized after loading button by ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7592787/valums-qq-fileuploader-dont-work-when-its-initialized-after-loading-button-by)

**EDIT**: The dialog code is not jQuery UI, it's custom code, basically, I trigger an event when I open a dialog, and I'm binded on this event to execute the FileUploader code.

**EDIT 2**: So I tried using a timeout of 1s after the popup to execute the FileUploader code, but still no go. Also tried to play with z-indexes, and no go.

**EDIT 3**: After several weeks it's still not working. I just can't seem to be able to find the cause of this problem. Here are two images that illustrate where the "hidden" file upload is (in red). And that it works outside, but not inside a dialog.

This is **outside** a dialog, and it works just fine:

[image: This is outside a dialog, and works]

This is the SAME exact form, but **inside** a dialog, but this doesn't work:

[image: Same exact form, inside a dialog, doesn't work]

**EDIT 4**: Just set up a JSFiddle with my code: http://jsfiddle.net/G5qP6/6/

However, as you can see, it works just fine in the JSFiddle, which get's me wondering, why does it doesn't work in my application.

Comment: Is your dialog nested inside of a `<form>`? I don't see one in the gc inspector.

Comment: Yes, it's before the <fieldset>, also, I use the same form inside and outside dialog, and outside, it works just fine.

Comment: To add to my previous comment, I don't have an upload form on the outside when I have an upload form in a dialog.

Comment: To clarify my previous comment. I never have 2 upload forms open at the same time.

Comment: @jValdron Anyway you can post an example of this somewhere so I can take a look?  I have had my fair share of widgets not working when placed inside a dialog.

Comment: @jValdron Just pull your dialog box widget and the qq code out and wire up a basic implementation of what you need to achieve.  We will get it working there, then you can integrate it back into the project and make sure it's still working.

Comment: @Jonathan I will try to setup a JS Fiddle, there's a lot of custom code in there, so I'll try to strip as much as possible. Will do in the next few days. Got some water problems that is more urgent ;)

Comment: @jValdron Cool.  Be sure to mention me in a comment so I notice the update.  Good luck!

Comment: @Jonathan I got a JSFiddle running, but seems to work fine in the JSFiddle...

Comment: @jValdron  I would suggest that you comment out all CSS and JS includes, except what is absolutely necessary to test the dialog.  From there, enable one at a time until you experience problems again.  That will give you an idea of what is causing the issue.  I wonder if changing the way you are handling positioning of the dialog has something to do with it...  Also, is jQuery UI running on your site?

Comment: @Jonathan Will give it a try! Yes I do have jQuery UI, but only a small selection of plugins (Widget, Mouse, Position, Draggable, Droppable and Sortable)

Comment: Your example works perfectly when I downloaded it from fiddle. Are you sure you're not having caching problems? http://tmp.itnews-bg.com/jValdron/

Comment: @jValdron Getting anywhere on this yet?

Comment: Well well, I got it figured out. The problem was that for the dialog to close when I was clicking on the overlay, I had an event on the overlay to close. And another one on the dialog that returned false (doh!), now I'm using stopPropagation, and it works fine. I tested this out by using the Chrome Console. I deleted absolutely everything in my document, except the dialog, and still wasn't working. Then I did $('.dialog').unbind(); in my console, and voila! Thanks a bunch to everyone on this matter!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand - you can't click the upload button but you can drag'n'drop.

If that's the case this seems to be a CSS problem. Probably an element is overlapping your upload button and therefore you're actually clicking on another element. Try to debug by setting borders and background color. If the upload button is being overlapped you'll see which element is overlapping it.

The other thing that comes to my mind is changing where you call `Upload.initializeUploads();`.
I would put it in `Dialog.init()` right after you've done `$('body').append(this.element);`.

Your example from fiddle works fine on my Firefox 10, Chrome 16, IE 8 and Opera 10(something).
My suggestion also works with the same browsers.

Your original code: http://tmp.itnews-bg.com/jValdron/ 
What I've changed: http://tmp.itnews-bg.com/jValdron/index-2.html